# Troubles with background-image

Tags: css

When I do this:

```
<style>
body{
    background-image: url('Pictures/a.jpg')
} 
</style>
```

it works. But when do this:

```
body {
    background-image:url(Pictures/a.jpg') 
}
```

it doesn't. I have a folder "Site" with css html and folder Pictures(in this fold pict)
why?
ty

Comment: you are missing a quote

Comment: There is an extra quote in the second example.

Comment: no,in css file we dont need quote at all

Comment: we are talking about outer .css in the 2nd example

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a quote.

```
body {
   background-image:url('Pictures/a.jpg');
}
```

I know W3Schools isn't the best example website but did cover this just fine. [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: in second example we are talking about outer .css

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this missing ' in `background-image:url(Pictures/a.jpg')` is the mistake only.

The reason of your problem may be the location of your .css and .html file. Are they placed in the same folder?